# Unpacking return value from function in List Comprehension

Tags: python, list

This code:

```
def f(v):
    return (v,v+1)

a = [f(i) for i in range(3)]
```

gives:

```
[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3)]
```

I wish to change the comprehension so that it gives:

```
[0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3]
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) you can use multiple `for ... in ...`:

```
>>> def f(v):
...     return (v,v+1)
...
>>> [x for i in range(3) for x in f(i)]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3]
```

Or, you can use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(f(i) for i in range(3)))
[0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3]
```