# Trouble unpacking returned tuple during list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've got a function that takes input and returns a 3 item tuple:

```
def f(a, b):
    x = a + 1
    y = x + 2
    z = y + 3
    return (x, y, z)
```

And I start with a set of tuples:

```
my_set = {(1, 2), (3, 4), ... (m, n)}
```

And I need to build a list, but the follow throws a TypeError:

```
[(a, b, x, y, z, (x, y, z)) for a, b in my_set for x, y, z in f(a, b)]
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

I was reviewing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28410577/unpacking-return-value-from-function-in-list-comprehension) post which shows a similar process, but for some reason the `for x, y, z ...` is throwing the exception and I'm not sure if I am just overlooking something small or not.

Comment: What is the exception ?

Comment: What's the TypeError?

Comment: Did you just tried to change the order of your arguments ?

`[(a, b, x, y, z, (x, y, z)) for x, y, z in f(a, b) for a, b in my_set ]`

Comment: @scharette Updated

Comment: @ltd9938 Updated

Comment: @Pils19 That wont work and will throw a `NameErorr` since `a` and `b` are not defined prior to calling `f(a, b)`. So I am not sure why people are upvoting your comment?

Comment: Maybe just try a `for` loop rather than a list comprehension. It will be easier to read and maintain that way

Comment: @C.Nivs I need to build the container, so a comprehension is better for this rather than a double `for` with a call to `append()`. Further, it still doesn't resolve and let me use `for x, y, z in f(a, b)`; tried and same error is thrown.

Comment: I'm looking for a dupe now, but in the meantime, switch to `for x, y, z in [f(a,b)]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's valid to unpack `f(a, b)` into `x, y, z`, but that's not what you're doing. `for x, y, z in f(a, b)` attempts to unpack *each element* of `f(a, b)` as if *each element* was an individual 3-tuple.

What you're looking for is a way to assign `f(a, b)` to something in a list comprehension, without iterating over it. There are workarounds for that, but I'd recommend just using a normal loop:

```
l = []
for a, b in my_set:
    x, y, z = f(a, b)
    l.append((a, b, x, y, z, (x, y, z)))
```

If you really want to use a list comprehension, one workaround is to loop over a dummy list `[f(a, b)]` instead of `f(a, b)`:

```
[(a, b, x, y, z, (x, y, z)) for a, b in my_set for x, y, z in [f(a, b)]]
```

Comment: Eh, I was looking for a dupe, but can't hit on the right keywords.  This'll do.

Comment: Ah. Good explanation. Yes in my mind I thought I could translate the `for x, y, z` to equate the `*` operator (unpack). But now I see that it is like trying to take each integer inside the tuple and it into 3 parts.

Comment: If only we could `[(a, b, x, y, z, (x, y, z)) for a, b, in my_set for x, y, z in *f(a, b)]`

Comment: That would take something like a (fictional) `where` keyword. `[(a, b, x, y, z, (x, y, z)) for a, b, in my_set where x, y, z = f(a, b)]`. This is interestingly a place where the equivalent in Haskell would be more succinct. `[let (x, y, z) = f a b in (a, b, x, y, z, (x, y, z)) | (a, b) <- my_set]`

Answer (score 1):

Let's understand your one-liner. Here's what you're actually doing:

```
for a, b in my_set:
    for i in f(a, b):
        print(i)
```

For every `a` & `b` in `my_set` function `f` is calculated. It outputs a tuple and then `i` is iterated over the tuple.

Because every item in the tuple is an integer,`for x, y, z in f(a, b)` doesn't work. Integer can't be split into several fractions.

You need:

```
[(a, b, *f(a, b), f(a, b)) for a, b in my_set]
```

In case efficiency matters you need `for` loop:

```
output = list()
for a, b in my_set:
    x, y, z = f(a, b)
    output.append((a, b, x, y, z, (x, y, z))
```

Comment: One-liner: True. Efficient: False. This requires 2x the number of calls to `f()`.